# Laravel 5 package exceptions not firing Hander's render method

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5

I'm working on a package and using the Orchestra/Testbench package for my Unit tests.

I'm trying to write a PHPUnit test that verifies the response is correct when an exception is thrown. In my repository I throw the following exception:

```
use Acme\Common\Exceptions\ValidationException;
...
throw new ValidationException($validator);
```

I have registered the handler class in the packages' service provider:

```
$this->app->singleton('Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler', 'Acme\Common\Exceptions\Handler');
```

However the render() method in the Handler class is not fired. Here's the render() method:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Acme\Common\Exceptions\ValidationException) {

        $message = implode(' ', array_flatten($exception->getMessages()->toArray()));

        $response = array('errorCode' => $exception->getCode());

        return \Response::make($response, 400);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Instead I just get the generic exception method:

```
Acme\Common\Exceptions\ValidationException: {"key":["The key field is required."]}
```

I even put a dd() at the start of the render() method but nothing. Am I missing some sort of setup with the Orchestra Testbench?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you overriding the constructor in this class by chance? I was having the exact same problem (trying to catch a ValidationException as well) and I didn't realize I had messed up the constructor. What is likely happening is that something is causing an exception to occur that is not being caught (since it is happening in your exception handler!). In my case, I overrode the constructor which meant that the parent class wasn't getting the Log class injected, which caused an exception to be thrown and halting things before the render method fired.

Answer (score 1):

You inject the Exception-class via variable "`$e`", but in your method you call a variable "`$exception`".

Since the `$exception`-variable isn't set, you should use your `$e`-variable.

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Acme\Common\Exceptions\ValidationException) {

        $message = implode(' ', array_flatten($e->getMessages()->toArray()));

        $response = array('errorCode' => $e->getCode());

        return \Response::make($response, 400);

    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```